# How do i convert this simple type xsd to a complex type XSD

Tags: xsd, wsdl

`I have a simple type xsd element which i want to convert to a complex type because i want the final wsdl to be document type literal format. Could you guys help?

```
<xsd:element name="Service">
    <xsd:simpleType>
      <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="loan.CreateLead" />
      </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
  </xsd:element>
```

I want this to be converted to a complex type with the same name element and having an enumeration value. Please let me know on this?
Thanks
Buyan

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it. The thing is, you can only extend/restrict one at a time, hence the two-steps approach.

I kept the original one unchanged for reference only, otherwise the first Service element could've been of "arestriction" type.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="Service">
        <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:enumeration value="loan.CreateLead"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:simpleType name="arestriction">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="loan.CreateLead"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:element name="Service1">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:simpleContent>
                <xsd:extension base="arestriction"/>
            </xsd:simpleContent>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```